# Laravel 5 Multiple relationships on same table with type

Tags: laravel, relationship, laravel-5.6

I've got two models: `User` & `Address`

In `Address`, there is a `type` attribute which it is an Enum column which can be set either to `SHIPPING` or `BILLING`.

`User` can have one `Address` in `SHIPPING` type and one in `BILLING` type.

Relationship as below:

```
public function billingAddr()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Models\Address')->where('type', Address::TYPE_BILLING);
}

public function shippingAddr()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Models\Address')->where('type', Address::TYPE_SHIPPING);
}
```

It works fine if I'm retrieving data:

```
$billingAddress = $user->billingAddr;
```

But if I'm creating a new relationship, I'll still need to manually insert the type, is there any way I can create through the relationship and that field will auto be filled?

For example:

```
// Record should be created with type auto set to BILLING
$user->billingAddr()->create($values);

// Record should be created with type auto set to SHIPPING
$user->shippingAddr()->create($values);
```

Comment: `manually insert the type` an example?

Comment: For example: I'll still need to do this eventhough I create through the relationship `$user->billingAddr()->create(['type' => 'BILLING']);`.

Comment: define that in your relationship model,isnt `TYPE_BILLING` equal to `Billing`?

Comment: Yes, `TYPE_BILLING` is the constant defined in `Address` model, the value for it is billing. But my question is, is there a way we can make the `type` attribute act like the `foreign_key`, so when you create through that relationship, you don't need to define it again. Example, `$user->billingAddr()->create($fields);` will have the `user_id` in `addresses` table auto-filled.

Answer (score 0):

You can define two functions in your `User` model:

```
function createBilling($address) {
    $this->billingAddr()->create(['address' => $address, 'type' => 'BILLING']);
}

function createShipping($address) {
    $this->shippingAddr()->create(['address' => $address, 'type' => 'SHIPPING']);
}
```

Comment: This is one of the ways, but is there a cleaner way to do this? Like setting these value inside the eloquent model's lifecycle events - `creating`.

Comment: That sounds way too complicated and not cleaner if you ask me.

Comment: I would argue that your DB structure isn't clean and a bit confusing at fisrt glance, because then you can't work with the relationships the way they work, for acomplishing what you want you would need to modify laravel core, which is not more clean than the answer @JacopoStanchi suggested imho.